# Merging two dataframes with the exact same columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have got 2 Dataframes:

```
df1
A B C D
1 7 9 3
1 4 9 4
2 2 1 
2 2 2 

df2
A B C D
1 7 9
1 4 9
2 2 1 5
2 2 2
```

I want to join them and that my result (df3) looks like this:

```
df3
A B C D
1 7 9 3
1 4 9 4
2 2 1 5
2 2 2
```

So I want to take over the values from column "D" from df1 and df2.

Comment: Check with `df1.update(df2)
`

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much ! :)